# OpenCV code for Face Detection(followed by eyes,nose & mouth detection) in android

Tags: java, android, c++, opencv, image-processing

I'm a beginner to OpenCV. I'm trying to do a sample android application to detect mouth in a given image using OpenCV . I searched in the internet and I couldn't find a proper android or java code which satisfy my requirement. But I have C++ code. I dont know how to translate it.

http://opencvfacedetect.blogspot.com/2010/10/face-detectionfollowed-by-eyesnose.html

Can you please help me to find a proper java or android code. Or else please help me with translate this C++ code into java, which I can use inside android application.

Thank you in advance.

### C++ code

```
/* program to detect facial features using opencv*/

/* detectFacialfeatures() is the main function that detects the face followed by Eyes,nose and mouth detection.*/

#include "stdafx.h"
    /**
     * Loads static images from database and detect faces
     */
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include<conio.h>
    #include "cv.h"
    #include "highgui.h"
    #include "cvaux.h"

    CvHaarClassifierCascade *cascade,*cascade_e,*cascade_nose,*cascade_mouth;
    CvMemStorage            *storage;
    char *face_cascade="haarcascade_frontalface_alt2.xml";
    char *eye_cascade="haarcascade_mcs_eyepair_big.xml";
    char *nose_cascade="haarcascade_mcs_nose.xml";
    char *mouth_cascade="haarcascade_mcs_mouth.xml";

    /*Mouth detect ion*/
    void detectMouth( IplImage *img,CvRect *r)
    {
       CvSeq *mouth;
       //mouth detecetion - set ROI
       cvSetImageROI(img,/* the source image */ 
                     cvRect(r->x,            /* x = start from leftmost */
                            r->y+(r->height *2/3), /* y = a few pixels from the top */
                            r->width,        /* width = same width with the face */
                            r->height/3    /* height = 1/3 of face height */
                           )
                    );
        mouth = cvHaarDetectObjects(img,/* the source image, with the estimated location defined */ 
                                    cascade_mouth,      /* the eye classifier */ 
                                    storage,        /* memory buffer */
                                    1.15, 4, 0,     /* tune for your app */ 
                                    cvSize(25, 15)  /* minimum detection scale */
                                   );

            for( int i = 0; i < (mouth ? mouth->total : 0); i++ )
            {

              CvRect *mouth_cord = (CvRect*)cvGetSeqElem(mouth, i);
              /* draw a red rectangle */
              cvRectangle(img, 
                          cvPoint(mouth_cord->x, mouth_cord->y), 
                          cvPoint(mouth_cord->x + mouth_cord->width, mouth_cord->y + mouth_cord->height),
                          CV_RGB(255,255, 255), 
                          1, 8, 0
                        );
            }
         //end mouth detection

    }

    /*Nose detection*/
    void detectNose( IplImage *img,CvRect *r)
    {
      CvSeq *nose;

      //nose detection- set ROI
      cvSetImageROI(img,                    /* the source image */ 
                    cvRect(r->x,            /* x = start from leftmost */
                           r->y , /* y = a few pixels from the top */
                           r->width,        /* width = same width with the face */
                           r->height  /* height = 1/3 of face height */
                          )
                   );


      nose = cvHaarDetectObjects(img, /* the source image, with the estimated location defined */ 
                                 cascade_nose,      /* the eye classifier */ 
                                 storage,        /* memory buffer */
                                 1.15, 3, 0,     /* tune for your app */ 
                                 cvSize(25, 15)  /* minimum detection scale */
                                );

      for( int i = 0; i < (nose ? nose->total : 0); i++ )
          {
              CvRect *nose_cord = (CvRect*)cvGetSeqElem(nose, i);

              /* draw a red rectangle */
              cvRectangle(img, 
                          cvPoint(nose_cord->x, nose_cord->y), 
                          cvPoint(nose_cord->x + nose_cord->width, nose_cord->y + nose_cord->height),
                          CV_RGB(0,255, 0), 
                          1, 8, 0
                        );

          }
    }

    /*Eyes detection*/
    void detectEyes( IplImage *img,CvRect *r)
    {
        char *eyecascade;
        CvSeq *eyes;
        int eye_detect=0;


       //eye detection starts
      /* Set the Region of Interest: estimate the eyes' position */

        cvSetImageROI(img,                    /* the source image */ 
              cvRect
              (
                  r->x,            /* x = start from leftmost */
                  r->y + (r->height/5.5), /* y = a few pixels from the top */
                  r->width,        /* width = same width with the face */
                  r->height/3.0    /* height = 1/3 of face height */
              )
          );

          /* detect the eyes */
          eyes = cvHaarDetectObjects( img,            /* the source image, with the estimated location defined */ 
                                      cascade_e,      /* the eye classifier */ 
                                      storage,        /* memory buffer */
                                      1.15, 3, 0,     /* tune for your app */ 
                                      cvSize(25, 15)  /* minimum detection scale */
                                    );

          printf("\no of eyes detected are %d",eyes->total);


            /* draw a rectangle for each detected eye */
            for( int i = 0; i < (eyes ? eyes->total : 0); i++ )
              {
                  eye_detect++;
                  /* get one eye */
                  CvRect *eye = (CvRect*)cvGetSeqElem(eyes, i);
                  /* draw a red rectangle */
                            cvRectangle(img, 
                                        cvPoint(eye->x, eye->y), 
                                        cvPoint(eye->x + eye->width, eye->y + eye->height),
                                        CV_RGB(0, 0, 255), 
                                        1, 8, 0
                                       );
               }


    }
    void detectFacialFeatures( IplImage *img,IplImage *temp_img,int img_no)
    {

        char image[100],msg[100],temp_image[100];
        float m[6];
        double factor = 1;
        CvMat M = cvMat( 2, 3, CV_32F, m );
        int w = (img)->width;
        int h = (img)->height;
        CvSeq* faces;
        CvRect *r;

        m[0] = (float)(factor*cos(0.0));
        m[1] = (float)(factor*sin(0.0));
        m[2] = w*0.5f;
        m[3] = -m[1];
        m[4] = m[0];
        m[5] = h*0.5f;

        cvGetQuadrangleSubPix(img, temp_img, &M);
        CvMemStorage* storage=cvCreateMemStorage(0);
        cvClearMemStorage( storage );

        if( cascade )
            faces = cvHaarDetectObjects(img,cascade, storage, 1.2, 2, CV_HAAR_DO_CANNY_PRUNING, cvSize(20, 20));
        else
            printf("\nFrontal face cascade not loaded\n");

        printf("\n no of faces detected are %d",faces->total);


        /* for each face found, draw a red box */
        for(int i = 0 ; i < ( faces ? faces->total : 0 ) ; i++ )
        {        
            r = ( CvRect* )cvGetSeqElem( faces, i );
            cvRectangle( img,cvPoint( r->x, r->y ),cvPoint( r->x + r->width, r->y + r->height ),
                         CV_RGB( 255, 0, 0 ), 1, 8, 0 );    

            printf("\n face_x=%d face_y=%d wd=%d ht=%d",r->x,r->y,r->width,r->height);

            detectEyes(img,r);
            /* reset region of interest */
            cvResetImageROI(img);
            detectNose(img,r);
            cvResetImageROI(img);
            detectMouth(img,r);
            cvResetImageROI(img);
        }
        /* reset region of interest */
          cvResetImageROI(img);

          if(faces->total>0)
            {
                sprintf(image,"D:\\face_output\\%d.jpg",img_no);
                cvSaveImage( image, img );
            }
    }

    int main( int argc, char** argv )
    {
        CvCapture *capture;
        IplImage  *img,*temp_img;
        int       key;

        char image[100],temp_image[100];


        /* load the classifier 
           note that I put the file in the same directory with
           this code */
        storage = cvCreateMemStorage( 0 );
            cascade = ( CvHaarClassifierCascade* )cvLoad( face_cascade, 0, 0, 0 );
        cascade_e = ( CvHaarClassifierCascade* )cvLoad( eye_cascade, 0, 0, 0 );
        cascade_nose = ( CvHaarClassifierCascade* )cvLoad( nose_cascade, 0, 0, 0 );
        cascade_mouth = ( CvHaarClassifierCascade* )cvLoad( mouth_cascade, 0, 0, 0 );



        if( !(cascade || cascade_e ||cascade_nose||cascade_mouth) )
            {
            fprintf( stderr, "ERROR: Could not load classifier cascade\n" );
            return -1;
            }

        for(int j=20;j<27;j++)
        {

             sprintf(image,"D:\\ptz images\\%d.jpg",j);

            img=cvLoadImage(image);
            temp_img=cvLoadImage(image);

            if(!img)
            {
            printf("Could not load image file and trying once again: %s\n",image);
            }
            printf("\n curr_image = %s",image);

            detectFacialFeatures(img,temp_img,j);
        }


        cvReleaseHaarClassifierCascade( &cascade );
        cvReleaseHaarClassifierCascade( &cascade_e );

        cvReleaseHaarClassifierCascade( &cascade_nose );
        cvReleaseHaarClassifierCascade( &cascade_mouth );
        cvReleaseMemStorage( &storage );

         cvReleaseImage(&img);
         cvReleaseImage(&temp_img);


        return 0;
    }
```

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 1):

There is an android prebuilt port of Opencv 3.0. 
http://opencv.org/downloads.html

Most of work in opencv is programmed on C++.

There are examples Java, such as face Detector in  (Quite simple) . I am not sure if there is mouth and eye detector.

Besides you can use your code, to program android application through JNI.

At the beginning (JNI) is quite complicated, but is the most elegant way to get maximum performance of the applications. Besides, you will be almost sure that the opencv desktop features are on android.

check this links: 
https://github.com/googlesamples/android-ndk/tree/master/hello-jni

https://developer.android.com/ndk/samples/sample_hellojni.html?hl=es
Hope this references helps.

Cheers.